# MySQL count statement

Tags: mysql, sql

I am using this statement to count the numbers of occurrences of a particular ID

```
SELECT cms_id, COUNT( * ) AS Number
FROM website
GROUP BY cms_id
ORDER BY  `website`.`cms_id` ASC 
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

However in another table I have the title name for each of the cms_id

```
cms_id cms_name   
1     wordpress
```

How can I then retrieve the name form the other table and show this instead of the cms_ID

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT  a.cms_id, b.cms_name, COUNT(*) AS Number -- <<== you can remove a.cms_id
FROM    website a
        INNER JOIN anotherTable b
            ON a.cms_id = b.cms_id
GROUP   BY a.cms_id, b.cms_name
ORDER   BY a.cms_id ASC 
LIMIT   0 , 30
```

To further gain more knowledge about joins, kindly visit the link below:

- [Visual Representation of SQL Joins](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html)